# add a save item to vscode editor context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Vscode noob here, trying to get a save item in the editor context menu. I've got as far as this:

```
{
    "name": "vsContextSave",
    "displayName": "vsContextSave",
    "description": "add save item to editor context menu",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "publisher": "njamescouk",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "license": "MIT License",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.40.0"
    },
    "contributes": {
        "menus": {
            "editor/context": [
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.files.save",
                    "group": "9_cutcopypaste",
                    "when": "editorTextFocus"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "__metadata": {}
}
```

When wrapped up in a directory in the .vscode\extensions directory vscode sees it and vsContextSave shows up in the extension list and is enabled. However I don't see a save item in the context menu.

edit:

I've inserted an activation event just before the metadata statement, but apparently I need a main module with an activate() function in it.

```
"activation Events": ["onStartupFinished"],
```

Comment: have you defined an empty activation function

Comment: no. where and how should I do so?

Answer (score 0):

these two files get you find, find file and save as context menu items in the editor.

extension.js:

no idea what this does but seems to be necessary

```
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const vscode = require("vscode");
function activate(context) {
};
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "mainContext",
    "displayName": "mainContext",
    "description": "add various items to editor context menu",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "publisher": "njamescouk",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "license": "MIT License",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.40.0"
    },
    "main": "./extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "menus": {
            "editor/context": [
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.files.save",
                    "group": "9_cutcopypaste",
                    "when": "editorTextFocus"
                },
                {
                    "command": "actions.find",
                    "group": "9_cutcopypaste",
                    "when": "editorTextFocus"
                },
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
                    "group": "9_cutcopypaste",
                    "when": "editorTextFocus"
                }
            ]
        },
        "commands": [
            {
                "title": "Save",
                "command": "workbench.action.files.save"
            },
            {
                "title": "Find",
                "command": "actions.find"
            },
            {
                "title": "Find file",
                "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen"
            }
        ]
    },
    "activationEvents": [
        "onStartupFinished"
    ],
    "__metadata": {}
}
```